# React - Data tables with React

Tags: reactjs

I would like to use one of the many table/data-grid components available to render a table. However, I am struggling to choose one as I have very specific requirements and I'm not sure if they are supported by them.

Ok so ideally I would like the table to initialise with only column headers (which are populated by data from a database). I would then like to be able to add a row (by clicking on a button), and be able to enter data into the cells and then save the data in that row to my database. The column headers are generated by form but there can feasibly be any number of them. Most of the examples for the various components seem to expect you to already know what your data is before you render the table. But this will not be the case for me.

I was considering Griddle but they don't have an editable cell option yet (it's only part of the roadmap) so unless I create my own custom function, I think that that is out for now.

I was just hoping for some guidance is choosing the best component for what I need!

Thanks for your time

Comment: `I would like to use one of the many table/data-grid components available to render a table`. Like what?

Comment: This question is really too broad for SO. What would help to improve: Name specific table/data-grids you are considering. Even then, choosing the right grid for your purpose is quite broad. Also: I am not sure what reactjs has to do with it. Or maybe break question down in smaller questions. Or maybe go with one option, as as soon as you get stuck, ask for help.

Comment: react-data-grid, griddle, react-bootstrap-table, react-grid, fixed-data-table but I'm struggling to find one that meets all my needs!